# How to convert an unsigned define variable in an signed define variable in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, unsigned, stringification

```
#define VERSION 1U

#define _VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(var) _VALUE_TO_STRING(var)

#define VERSION_STRING VALUE_TO_STRING(VERSION)

char readMe[] = "The current version of this document is " VERSION_STRING ".";
```

...

I have this part of the code where I need a global string(readMe) to be created at initialization time. 
The output of the above code will be -> The current version of this document is 1U.
So what I want is to get rid of that "U".
Is there a chance that I fix this with preprocessor functions?(like transform the unsigned defined value to an signed define value...)?

Comment: and why don't you `#define VERSION 1` instead?

Comment: The macro `VALUE_TO_STRING` will just take whatever C code you put inside the parentheses and make a string out of it. So for instance `VALUE_TO_STRING(1 + 2 + 3)` is not `"6"`, but `"1 + 2 + 3"`. This is because macro expansion happens in the preprocessor stage, so the expression has not been evaluated to `6` and is still just plain, unprocessed C code.

Comment: Also, in my opinion it's just better to for instance just declare `#define VERSION_STRING "1"` explicitly than to use a macro like this.

Comment: Unless you expect to have a version 2.1billion, why do you even care about making the version number unsigned? Even if you only ever assign the version number to a single byte, you still need to get to version 127 before you should even care...

Comment: i cant use 1 because it is used by a library and need to be unsigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a pre-processor method to take out the `U` from `VERSION`. However, you can combine them. I would suggest:

```
#define UNSIGNED_VERSION 1

#define VERSION UNSIGNED_VERSION ## U

#define _VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(var) _VALUE_TO_STRING(var)

#define VERSION_STRING VALUE_TO_STRING(UNSIGNED_VERSION)

char readMe[] = "The current version of this document is " VERSION_STRING ".";
```